# upload image and use it in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin and I have a problem with image uploading. I need do something like what a custom-header contain where I can upload image and use it. I try to use http://goo.gl/JHna9 It upload image successfully but I need something more. I need to find out way how tell to wordpress that uploaded picture was for my plugin and next get all pictures uploaded through my plugin.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several choices.

1. Use the same upload function to create a DB entry (But I would not reccomand it if it is not absolutely neccessary)
2. use the same function you are uploading to create a hidden custom field - associating it somehow (with a key) to your plugin (after all - an attachment is only a taxonomy for some kind of post - and has it´s own metadata. )
3. put your attachments in a different folder (can be usefull - depending on what you want to do)